# Trying to use react-to-print to print from within a Component

Tags: reactjs, printing

I am very new to React programming and I am trying to add React-to-Print to print a Component were the print button is in the component ?
This code shows a list of rows that I want to print the window.print() only print what is displayed on the screen I need it to display all the rows. But I can't figure out how to add React-to-Print to that button ?

Please See the code below . any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Window from '../../components/window';
import InfiniteTable from "../../components/infiniteTable";
import { BackButton } from "../../components/backButton";
import { WindowHeader } from '../../components/window/WindowHeader';
import Translate from '../../components/translate';
import * as utils from '../../utils/utils';







class RemainingProductsWindow extends Component {




    render() {

        return (

            <React.Fragment>




                {this.props.show &&
                    <Window show={this.props.show}

                        title={<Translate k="Products" />}
                        dismiss={() => { this.props.closeDialog("remainingProductsDialog"); }}
                        bodyClassName="mb-3 ml-3 mr-3  flex-row"
                    header={<div className="window-header flex flex-row">

                       
                            <BackButton onClick={() => { this.props.closeDialog("remainingProductsDialog"); }} />
                            <WindowHeader data={[
                                { key: <Translate k="WaveID" />, value: this.props.selectedWave ? utils.shortGUID(this.props.selectedWave.waveID) : '' },
                                { key: <Translate k="Items_Total" />, value: this.props.productDetails ? this.props.productDetails.count: 0 },
                                { key: <Translate k="Items_Remaining_Total" />, value: this.props.productDetails && this.props.productDetails.data ? this.props.productDetails.data.reduce((acc, curr) => acc += curr.remainingItems, 0): 0 } 
                            ]}
                            />

                        <i className="fas fa-print" onClick={(e) => { console.log('Print Button', e); window.print()  }}></i>


                        </div>}
                    >
                        <div className="flex flex-full flex-row">
                             
                            <InfiniteTable
                                className="product-details-table"
                                data={this.props.productDetails ? this.props.productDetails.data: null }
                                onClick={() => { }}
                                onDblClick={() => { }}
                                keyID=""
                                selectedID={null}
                                hidden={[]}
                                statusMessage={<Translate k="No_product_details_found" />}
                               //updateData={this.updateProductDetails}
                            />

                            <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                __html: `.layout-center { overflow: initial; } `
                            }} />
                        </div>
                        </Window>}


            </React.Fragment>);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    ...state
});






export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RemainingProductsWindow);
```

Comment: After installation of this module you need to import ReactToPrint component and add it inside your component. Like in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/rzdhd?file=/example/index.js

Comment: I have tried doing that the problem is that all the examples I have seen, it seem you have to have you run the example class outside the component with it's trigger and button however my class RemainingProductsWindow has the button on the inside of the component and I just can't see how to make it work. I wanted to replace the window.print() in the print button with the logic the print the whole list out not just the current screen.   Thanks